# JqGrid - Adding Select DropDown to edit form and filling from Database

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am a newbie so go easy! But I am trying to fill a `select` dropdown from a MySQL database on an edit form for a jQGrid.

Here is my code so far:

```
colNames:['ID','CampaignName','Status'],
colModel:[
    {
        name:'ID', 
        index:'ID', 
        width:55,
        editable:true,
        editoptions:{
            readonly:true,
            size:10
        }
    }, 
    {
        name:'CampaignName',
        index:'CampaignName',
        width:120,
        align:'left',
        editable:true,
        editoptions:{
            size:25
        }
    }, 
    {
        name:'Status',
        index:'Status',
        width:80,
        align:'left',
        editable: true,
        edittype:'select'
    }
],
```

But I need the `status` field to be a `select` filled from the database. I have a PHP file called 'StatusDropDown.php' which I have used before to fill a Select Box (see below). How can I get this to work on the edit form on my grid?

```
<select id="StatusID" name="StatusID" onchange="StatusChanged(this.id)">
    <?php
        include("StatusDropDown.php");
    ?>
    <OPTION VALUE=0> 
        <?php echo $List ?>
    </SELECT>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks JC

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link below to implement my dropdown successfully.

http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/07/02/jqgrid-dynamically-loading-select-options.aspx

The thing is you gotta make sure the output of your php is json, and I used json_encode() in php.